# use mnemonic in bitcoin rpc using bitcoin cli with none legacy wallets

Tags: bitcoind, bitcoin-cli, mnemonic-seed, wallet-import

I have my 12 words (mnemonic) and I know that I can get zpriv, xpriv, private keys and anything from that. but when I try to import them to my bitcoin rpc, I can only import them into legacy wallets which are going to deprecate and generates addresses using a derived private key

I searched everywhere, but there is no proper way that I can import my prev wallet into bitcoin rpc.

I already tried `sethdseed`, `importpriv` , `importmulti`

all of them are for legacy wallets which I explained that they are not suitable now.
so please provide a working solution to import my hd wallet (mnemonic) into  my bitcoin node rpc

update:
as "Pieter Wuille" mentioned, I know that there is no straight way for doing this, Im trying to find out should I convert my mnemonic to something (descriptor for example) and import it.

a nodejs example would be grate.

tnx

Answer (score 4):

Bitcoin Core's wallet does not support any kind of mnemonic seed phrases at all, not in legacy wallets, and not in descriptor wallets.

What is in theory possible is to convert the phrase (using external software) to an [*output descriptor*](https://github.com/bitcoin/bitcoin/blob/v24.0.1/doc/descriptors.md), and import that into a Bitcoin Core descriptor wallet using the `importdescriptors` RPC. I don't know if user-friendly software for that exists already, though.

Comment: how can I convert my mnemonic to descriptor in nodejs ?

Comment: I read in https://chainquery.com/bitcoin-cli/importdescriptors that importdescriptors may take an hour to complete. thats so long! there isnt any other way for this? Im trying to build a bitcoin wallet rest system, so this solution wont work for me if it takes 1 hour for every wallet

Comment: Is this any help: https://stackoverflow.com/q/69119382/477035

Comment: @Godfather As I said, I don't know if any usable software exists right now to do this, I was speaking hypothetically. The simple answer is just that Bitcoin Core does not support mnemonic phrases or seeds; you need to use other wallet software to do what you're looking to do.

Comment: @pieter-wuille so if I want to create a bitcoin wallet rest service, running a bitcoin node is not a solution. then what is the solution to do such a thing ?

Comment: @Godfather Run a Bitcoin node by all means, just don't use Bitcoin Core's built-in wallet. Instead, run whatever wallet software that implements the features you need, and connect it to the Bitcoin node.

Comment: @PieterWuille thanks a lot for the Idea. do you know any 3rd party package or libraries for this in nodejs? or anything with a SDK than I can use in nodejs?

Comment: I'm not familiar with the nodejs/js world.